# React-pdf "Highlight text on the page" is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

I am trying to implement [React-pdf](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/wiki/Recipes#highlight-text-on-the-page) pdf highlighting feature:

```js
import React, { useMemo, useState } from 'react';
// import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack';

import samplePDF from './test.pdf';

// https://gist.github.com/wojtekmaj/f265f55e89ccb4ce70fbd2f8c7b1d95d
function highlightPattern(text, pattern) {
  const splitText = text.split(pattern);

  if (splitText.length <= 1) {
    return text;
  }

  const matches = text.match(pattern);

  return splitText.reduce((arr, element, index) => (matches[index] ? [
    ...arr,
    element,
    <mark key={index}>
      {matches[index]}
    </mark>,
  ] : [...arr, element]), []);
}

export default function Test() {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

  // const textRenderer = useMemo((textItem) => {
  //   return highlightPattern(textItem.str, searchText);
  // }, [searchText]);

  function onChange(event) {
    setSearchText(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Document
        file={samplePDF}
        // onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
      >
        <Page
          pageNumber={1}
          // customTextRenderer={textRenderer}
        />
      </Document>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="search">Search:</label>
        <input type="search" id="search" value={searchText} onChange={onChange} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Please note that I have commented the `textRenderer` function. If I uncomment it (still the Page component's prop is commented) application is crashed with

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'str')

Reason could be `textItem` is null or undefined. But how can I fix this with `useMemo`?

Comment: did you fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using `useCallback` as shown in the [recipe](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/wiki/Recipes#highlight-text-on-the-page)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).